# Generating and a tone with frequency x for duration y and keep other code executing during tone

Tags: python, multithreading, automation, fft

On a high level what I'm trying to achieve is automation of data recording for FFT analysis. Right now I'm generating a constant tone using a tone generator, then recording the output of my system. When recording is finished the tone is stopped. Repeat this for the entire frequency domain. Afterwards all data is processed with various analysis steps (e.g. FFT). All of this is done in Python3

I've been trying to automate the boring stuff in this procedure and I would like to take out the manual frequency sweep.

What I need for that is something to generate a tone of frequency x for duration y. When the tone is enabled I need the code execution to continue for  recording.

In my searches thus far I have found winsound. However winsound.beep doesn't work with the asynchronous option of winsound and I'd like to avoid working with recorded signals. Right now I'm out of ideas. Is there anybody that can help me?

Example code:

```
import winsound
winsound.Beep(500,1000)
print('this is not simultaneously printed with the sound playing')
```

Comment: it seems you will have to use [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) to run two threads at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

@furas Thank you for the feedback, with your suggestion of using threading I've managed to have a proof of concept working. I'm providing here the feedback and my basic code in case anybody else runs into this question.
    import threading
    import time
    import logging
    import winsound

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='(%(threadName)-10s) %(message)s',
                    )

def makeTone(freq,dur):
    logging.debug('Starting Sound with f=%sHz for t=%ss',freq,dur)
    winsound.Beep(freq,dur)

    logging.debug('Sound stopped')

def recorder():
    logging.debug('Startrecording')
    time.sleep(3)
    logging.debug('Stoprecording')

frequency = 500 #Hz
duration = 5000 #ms
makeTone = threading.Thread(name='makeTone', target=makeTone,args=(frequency, duration))
recorder = threading.Thread(name='recorder', target=recorder)

makeTone.start()
recorder.start()
```